# Count distinct id case when

Tags: sas

I have table tb with these variables: id,year(it take values from 2007 to 2014 ,each year might be more than once) age_category(form 1 to 4)
I need to count distinct id for each year using different aga category.

I tried but not getting the result.

```
proc sql; 
  create table new as
  select 
  COUNT( distinct id CASE WHEN year = 2007 and agecat=1 THEN id else 0 END) as yr_2007,
  COUNT( distinct id CASE WHEN year = 2008 and agecat=1 THEN id else 0 END) as yr_2008,
  COUNT( distinct id CASE WHEN year = 2009 and agecat=1 THEN id else 0 END) as yr_2009
from tb;
```

Comment: You can do a `UNION` for each case . `SELECT count(distinct id)where.... UNION SELECT count....`

Comment: So, you just need the numbers? It doesn't matter if they're in many columns and a single row or a single column and many rows? In that case, you 
can do without the unions and simply group by year and agecat. Use a where-statement if you want to restrict it to a given agecat. 

``proc sql; 
 create table new as
 select year, agecat, COUNT(distinct id) as distinct_ids
 from tb
 where agecat=1
 group by year, agecat
;``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will need to use a construct such as

```
COUNT(distinct CASE when year=<year> and agecat=1 then id else . end) as year_<year>
```

Coding-wise this is probably the wrong approach, especially if you want the distinct counts for each `agecat`. You would need one expression for each `year` and `agecat` combination.

The transformation of the year values from being in a column to being in a column-name is a pivot (and data structure change) from data to metadata and leads to headaches.  There are procedures such as `PROC TABULATE` and `PROC REPORT` for producing output that displays categorical data in columnar form.  `PROC TRANSPOSE` can also be used to perform these pivots.

Sample code:

```
ods _all_ close;
ods html5 path='c:\temp' file='catcounts.html';
options nocenter nodate nonumber;

data have;
  do id = 1 to 1000;
    do year = 2007 to 2014;
      if ranuni(123) < 0.75 then continue;
      agecat = ceil(4*ranuni(123));
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

* ugly, expression pivot;
proc sql;
  create table want(label="Unique ID count by year") as
  select
    count (distinct case when year=2007 and agecat=1 then id else . end) as yr_2007_age1_idcount,
    count (distinct case when year=2008 and agecat=1 then id else . end) as yr_2007_age2_idcount,
    count (distinct case when year=2009 and agecat=1 then id else . end) as yr_2007_age3_idcount
    /* potentially many more */
  from have;

* clean, categorical counts;

proc sql;
  create table counts(label="Unique ID count by year and agecat") as
  select
    year, agecat, count(distinct id) as idCount
  from have
  group by year, agecat;

proc print noobs data=counts;
  title "PRINT: Categorical counts results - output limited with where statement";
  where year between 2010 and 2015 and agecat in (1,2);
run;

* pivot categorical, limited to agecat=1;
proc transpose data=counts out=counts_agecat1 prefix=year_;
  id year;
  var idCount;
  where agecat=1;
quit;

proc print noobs data=counts_agecat1;
  title "PRINT: ID Counts for agecat=1";
  title2 "Pivot made with TRANSPOSE and limited with where statement";
run;

proc transpose data=counts out=counts_wide prefix=count_ delimiter=_;
  id year agecat;
  var idCount;
  where agecat in (1,2);
quit;

proc print noobs data=counts_wide;
  title "PRINT: ID counts for each year and agecat";
  title2 "Pivot made with TRANSPOSE and ID year agecat and limited with where statement";
run;

proc tabulate data=counts;
  title "Tabulate: Display the pre-computed categorical counts";
  class year agecat;
  var idCount;
  table year='',agecat*idCount=''*sum=''*f=best12./nocellmerge;
run;

proc tabulate data=counts;
  title "Tabulate: Display the pre-computed categorical counts";
  class year agecat;
  var idCount;
  table agecat,year=''*idCount=''*sum=''*f=best12./nocellmerge;
run;

proc report data=counts;
  title "Report:  Display the pre-computed categorical counts";
  column year agecat,idCount ;
  define year / group;
  define agecat / across;
run;

ods _all_ close;
```

[image]